# Search database table with jquery ui autocomplete in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, pdo, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to search my users table using the jquery ui autocomplete widget.
The two fields from my users table, which I would like to search for:

```
TABLE `users`
 `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
```

**The view**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#searchFriends" ).autocomplete({
          source: "/friend/showFriends",
          minLength: 1
        });
      });
</script>

<input type="search" id="searchFriends" placeholder="find friends"/>
```

**The controller**

```
/**
 * Show friends
 */
 public function showFriends()
 {
     $this->View->render('friend/index', array(
         'privateFriends' => FriendModel::displayFriends(),
         'searchFriends' => FriendModel::searchUsers()
      ));
 }
```

**The model**

```
/**
 * Search users table
 */
public static function searchUsers()
{
if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_name LIKE :term or user_email LIKE :term) ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 5");

    $query->execute(array(':term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    $friends = $query->fetchAll();

    $friend_usernames = array(); 

    foreach($friends as $friend) { 
            $friend_usernames[] = $friend->user_name;
            $friend_usernames[] = $friend->user_email;
        }

    /* output results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($friend_usernames);
    }
}
```

The Model puts out the usernames as JSON, as desired.
However, I do not know how to get this JSON list of users to the input field. When I am searching for a user in the input field nothing turns up, if I put the JSON right into the view it works as intended though.
I am not using any kind of framework or cms.
I would be very happy about any kind of help!

Comment: You're not likely to get a different result than from yesterday's question just by reposting it. Instead you should try to narrow down the scope: the problem with this question is that it's too broad -- for example I can see a problem with the autocomplete initialiser being called before building the corresponding element (ie. wrap it in a `.ready` handler), but I can't be sure if that's the problem or even related as I know next to nothing about mvc

Comment: Great! Thank you for your feedback! I am desperate that is why I reposted the question hoping that on a working day I will get more answers than at the weekend. I will narrow it down! Thank you!